# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, noclassdeffounderror, apache-spark-1.6

I am using IntelliJ 2016.3  version.

```
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  object Versions {
    val spark = "1.6.3"
  }

  val projectName = "example-spark"

  val common = Seq(
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
  )

  val customLibraryDependencies = Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % Versions.spark % "provided",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % Versions.spark % "provided",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % Versions.spark % "provided",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % Versions.spark % "provided",

    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka" % Versions.spark
      exclude("log4j", "log4j")
      exclude("org.spark-project.spark", "unused"),

    "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.1.0",

    "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.10",

    "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-log4j12" % "1.7.10"
      exclude("log4j", "log4j"),

    "log4j" % "log4j" % "1.2.17" % "provided",

    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4" % "test"
  )
```

I have been  getting below run time exception., even though i mentioned all the dependencies correctly as shown above.[image: Libraries- screen shot]

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext
    at example.SparkSqlExample.main(SparkSqlExample.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
```

Investigated more on this web.And found that this is mainly due to in-appropriate entries in `buld.sbt` or version mismatches.But in my case everything looks good as shown above.
Please suggest where did i do wrong here?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `spark-sql_2.11` and such?

Comment: @philantrovert! Since we are using %% while mentioning dependencies, sbt is intelligent enough to append the scala version with an underscore. As we mentioned above scalaVersion := "2.11.7" ., sbt get it as 2.11 and append it to the dependency as spark-sql_2.11 finally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess this is because you marked your dependencies as "provided", but apparently you (or IDEA) don't provide them.

Try to remove the "provided" option or (my preferred way): move the class with the main method to `src/test/scala`